# Pandas Groupby - naming aggregate output column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `groupby` command which looks like this:

```
df.groupby(['year', 'month'], as_index=False).agg({'users':sum})
```

Is there a way I can name the `agg` output something other than 'users' during the groupby command?  For example, what if I wanted the sum of users to be total_users?  I could rename the column after the groupby is complete, but wonder if there is another way.

Answer (score 5):

Per the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once):

> If a dict is passed, the keys will be used to name the columns.
>   Otherwise the function’s name (stored in the function object) will be
>   used.
>
> In [58]: grouped['D'].agg({'result1' : np.sum,    ....:
>   'result2' : np.mean})

In your case:

```
df.groupby(['year', 'month'], as_index=False).users.agg({'total_users': np.sum})
```

Comment: Thats a great answer!
in this case **users** is the field you are aggregating on and **total_users** is new name of the field you are giving.

Answer (score 5):

I like @Alexander answer, but there is also `add_prefix`:

```
df.groupby(['year','month']).agg({'users':sum}).add_prefix('total_')
```

Comment: Is there a way to just rename only the `aggregated` columns? I think above code will also rename the `year` and `month` columns, if I am not mistaken. Appreciate your help.